# Can I render hole HTML page with react-native-webview?

Tags: react-native, google-pay, react-native-webview

So the question is: Can i render the response from the back(html page) with react-native-webview?

Comment: Please add a little more detail. Are you wanting to post a message in which you can then read within the React Native context? Are you wanting to interact with the WebView? If so, use postMessage, are you wishing to get the HTML as a string in React Native? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to render html page with confirmation form which is send by bank in response to my post request.
In this form user have to insert confirmation code to confirm the payment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this example will help you
In web

```js
<script>
  window.postMessage("Sending data from Web");
</script>
```

In React Native

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default class App extends Component {
  
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <WebView
             ref="webview"
             onMessage={this.onMessage}
          />
        );
    }

  onMessage(data) {
  
  alert(data);
}
}
```

Comment: What does data stands for?

Comment: the response from web.

Comment: So now I need to add source prop with html to this example, right?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can render whole html page with react-native-webview

Comment: If it's possible could you provide small example please?
Because i've tried and always getting blank white screen.

Comment: My code looks like this: 
return (
            <View>
            <WebView
                originWhitelist={['*']}
                source={{ html:  htmlResponse}}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                ignoreSslError={true}
            />
            </View>
        );
    }